# How to have a layer with many images that scale?

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, image

I know that in `OpenLayers` you can add Features to a Vector Layer which each have image but then they will not scale (i.e. their size stays the same independent of the current zoom) or at least I do not know how to make them scale. For example:

```
            var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
            var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,0)
            .transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject()), 
            {some:'data'},
            {externalGraphic: 'http://www.gatesms.eu/img/loga/java.png', graphicHeight: 30,graphicWidth: 30});
            var feature2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(1,1)
            .transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject()), 
            {some:'data'},
            {externalGraphic: 'http://blog.tiger.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Duke256.png', graphicHeight: 30,graphicWidth: 30});
            vectorLayer.addFeatures([feature,feature2]);
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

On the other hand the scaling of image works fine if you set an image for an Image Layer but then you can have only a single image in a layer.

```
            var options = {   
                opacity: 1.0, 
                isBaseLayer: false,
                numZoomLevels: 20,
                transparent: 'true'
            };
            var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(WEST,SOUTH,EAST,NORTH)
                .transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject());                    
            var gO = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image('Image',
                'http://www.gatesms.eu/img/loga/java.png',
                extent,
                new OpenLayers.Size(1,1),
                options);  
            map.addLayer(gO);
```

My question is: **How to have, in `OpenLayers`, many images on a single layer that will scale as in the above case?**

Answer (score 3):

I would use style's context object which calculates graphicWidth and graphicHeight depending on current map resolution. It applies to you first option (Vector layer).